I can't seem to install Steam correctly on my Debian-based version of Linux. Any solutions?
I tried using "sudo apt-get install libc6-i386", but it only led to more errors. It is stating that I am now missing "libGL.so.1" and "libdrm.so.2".

try sudo apt-get install steam.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

When you take your question to a release that supported Debian (or if Debian based, whatever OS that is), don't forget to provide your actual product & especially release details; as deb packages are built for specific releases, thus knowing the release is required unless you're happy to risk dep hell or package problems.  Also re-read your question, either your command contains a typo OR your command is incorrect (for Debian and Ubuntu too)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1152995367667896456/1321746087253643295/Screenshot_2024-12-26_1.43.35_AM.png?ex=676e5b78&is=676d09f8&hm=6614b7d9f547fd360a534d590ac67e430ad8168ad4883b63c28629d1c1ece76c& https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1152995367667896456/1321746087253643295/Screenshot_2024-12-26_1.43.35_AM.png?ex=676e5b78&is=676d09f8&hm=6614b7d9f547fd360a534d590ac67e430ad8168ad4883b63c28629d1c1ece76c&

Without knowing your actual OS details; pictures of errors don't help. Sure I can run a command and get the package available for all Ubuntu product/releases, and Debian releases too... but without knowing exactly what you're using I won't know which of the ~28 results I'd get from a CLI enquiry asking for that detail applies to you.  As you know what you're actually using, you could run those enquiries yourself & thus know which apply to your unstated system. As stated, deb packages are built for specific systems, and errors are usually when you're using different to what it was built for
